# Maven cargo plugin - redeploy specific deployable in standalone container?

Tags: maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, cargo

I'm currently working on a project that consists of several services written in Java that are accessed by a Ruby/Rails front-end.  In an attempt to simplify local development, I've created a separate project that adds all of our service WAR projects as dependencies, and uses the cargo-maven-plugin to deploy each of these as a deployable inside of a single embedded Jetty instance.

The issue I'm having is that I'd like to be able to tell cargo to re-deploy a single WAR out of the several that are being run at a time.  Starting the entire set of services from scratch takes a bit, and is really unnecessary when only one deployable has actually changed.  As far as I can tell, the `cargo:redeploy` goal only works for non-standalone containers, and I also haven't been able to find any documentation that its possible to specify what you want to re-deploy on the command line.

Is there a way to tell cargo to re-deploy a single deployable from the command line?  I'm thinking of something along the lines of `mvn cargo:redeploy -DgroupId=com.foo.bar -DartifactId=baz`

Apologies if this isn't clear, or if there is a different approach that I should be taking entirely - I'm relatively new to Java development and Maven.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest war file to your local machine, then redeploy using the following pattern:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.foo.bar -DartifactId=baz -Dversion=1.x -Dpackaging=war -Dfile=C:/cargo.jar
```